# mark formControl as validated/checked?

Tags: angular

I would like to show an error message below my input field when the input is not valid but only after the form has been submitted.

I could simply use a boolean and toggle it as soon as the form has submitted and take this as a condition for showing the message but I can't do this in my application as it is a bit more complex.

When submitting the reactive form, I mark each control as touched and in the *ngIf for the error hint I use the touched boolean as a condition.

```
Object.keys(selectForm.controls).forEach(key => {
   selectForm.get(key).updateValueAndValidity();
   if(!selectForm.get(key).valid) {
     selectForm.get(key).markAsTouched();
   } 
})
```

this solution works not perfectly because the error hint text also pops up when the user just "touches" the input.

```
<form [formGroup]="selectForm">
    <p-dropdown [options]="items" formControlName="selected" placeholder="Select" (onChange)="save()"></p-dropdown>
    <p-message *ngIf="selected.invalid && selected.errors.required && selected.touched" severity="error" text="Field is required"></p-message>
</form>
```

basically I am looking at something like `nestedForm.get(key).markAsChecked()`
 but this doesn't exist.

What is the solution here?

Comment: Could you share your html with us? Do you use `FormBuilder`?

Comment: @ahmeticat i updated my post, and yes I do use FormBuilder

Comment: What is your form group name? `selectform` or `nestedform` ?

Comment: selectForm is a subForm of nestedForm but to it shouldn't matter. To make things easier you can think of it as the same form. I also updated my post again so it is not confusing.

Comment: Hopely,you can not use form into form

Comment: i am not sure what you mean but this shouldnt be relevant to the original issue anyways

Comment: @M4V3N What do you mean by making the control '_checked_' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `errorMessageBindingStrategy` of `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators`.

You just have to set `"errorMessageBindingStrategy":1` in your app.component.ts like this:

```
 ngOnInit(){
    //if you want to apply global configuration then use below code. 
    ReactiveFormConfig.set({
      "validationMessage":{
        "required":"This field is required"
        },
        "reactiveForm":{
          "errorMessageBindingStrategy":1
        }});
  }
```

And set the `submitted` property of `RxFormGroup` as true on the submit method through which you want to display error message like this:

```
 OnSubmit() {
    this.selectForm.submitted = true;
  }
```

Complete Component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms"
import { RxFormBuilder, RxFormGroup, RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-errormessagestrategy-onsubmit-validator',
  templateUrl: './errormessagestrategy-onsubmit.component.html'
})
export class ErrormessagestrategyOnsubmitValidatorComponent implements OnInit {
  selectForm: RxFormGroup

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectForm = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.group({
      userName: ['', RxwebValidators.required()],
      password: ['', RxwebValidators.required()],
      address: this.formBuilder.group({
        city: ['', RxwebValidators.required()]
      })
    });

  }

  OnSubmit() {
    this.selectForm.submitted = true;
  }


}
```

Complete HTML Code

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="selectForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>User Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="userName" class="form-control"  />
       <small class="form-text text-danger">{{selectForm.controls.userName.errorMessage}}<br/></small>  
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="password" class="form-control"  />

      <small class="form-text text-danger">{{selectForm.controls.password.errorMessage}}<br/></small>
      </div>


        <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="selectForm.controls.address">
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="city" class="form-control" />
            <small class="form-text text-danger">{{selectForm.controls.address.controls.city.errorMessage}}<br/></small>
        </div>

      <button (click)="OnSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqv2b5?file=src/app/errormessagestrategy-onsubmit.component.ts)

Comment: unfortunately I can't use a framework like this. It would take up too much time to rewrite all the forms.